# Looking to expand my Spanish guitar repertoire

Tags: learning, exercises, classical-guitar, repertoire

I'm a middle-level guitarist with a sort of rag-tag set of music under my fingers. I've recently become transfixed by the music of Paco de Lucia, Carcassi (I know, he's Italian), and Segovia. I'm trying to learn more classical-Spanish pieces, but I'm not familiar with many artists or authors.

So I'm looking for classical-Spanish guitarristas (more like Segovia than Paco - I like flamenco too, but not for the purpose of this question) and pieces that are relatively accessible. By relatively accessible, I mean easier than Recuerdos de la Alhambra, for example.

In addition, if there were a well-known set of exercises for Spanish classical guitar, I'm all ears. Please note that this is different than the inopportunely named [Spanish guitar music](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/3095/im-a-flamenco-guitar-player-how-to-start-playing-blues) question.

Answer (score 8):

I recommend Fernando Sor's studies for guitar as transcribed by Andres Segovia. These studies are both highly instructive as well as beautiful works unto themselves. Given your familiarity with Andres Segovia, the music of Fernando Sor (a major influence on Segovia's development as a musician/composer) would be a logical next step.

See

1. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fernando_Sor
2. http://www.sheetmusicplus.com/title/20-Studies-for-Guitar/2875491

Comment: I followed up on Sor, and he's fantastic! Thank you very much - this was a great suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

[Mauro Giuliani](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mauro_Giuliani) and [Dionisio Aguado](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dionisio_Aguado) are will known classical guitarist, both have a lot of etudes to work on. Their works are popular among classical guitarists.
Since you mentioned "Recuerdos De La Al Hambra" you can check Tarrega's other works, he is one of the most celebrated guitarists.

Answer (score 2):

Another little known gem is Luigi Legnani, a friend of Nicolo Paganini. While there are some published guitar works by Paganini, I find them very boring. They lack the *fury* of the violin works; but being mostly moving chords over drones, they could serve as nice exercises. Legnani, on the other hand, is a firecracker at a Quaker meeting. Dark marcato basslines, dramatic flashes and flares, and that harmonic-minor/phrygian thing that the Spanish masters do so well. Many of the World Favorite Guitar collections include a piece of his; and it is often the most exciting piece in the whole book.